# How to install Mathpix Snip in Ubuntu 22.04 using terminal?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, 22.04, latex, ocr

I installed Mathpix Snip in Ubuntu 20.04 by following the following instructions from their [documentation](https://mathpix.com/docs/snip/linux-overview):

> *Getting Snip app and launching it from your Terminal (Advanced)*
>
> Open your terminal. And execute the following
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads
> wget https://download.mathpix.com/linux/Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0050.AppImage -O Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage
> ```
>
> (Note: The link might change, check it on https://mathpix.com/)
>
> ```
> chmod 777 ./Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage
> ./Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage"
> ```

But now I have Ubuntu 22.04 and when I tried to use the same instructions I was not able to install.

Comment: Did you read the first part of the page you linked? According to the documentation you linked, if you have GNOME, you need to add an extension. The docs also say that the app doesn't work with Wayland and they recommend you use Xorg or another desktop environment entirely.

Comment: I downloaded that extension is  a folder, but now how I can to install that folder?

Comment: What folder? Please be more clear/specific.

Comment: This extension: TopIcons Plus, but appeared this message "Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6. Probably you should upgrade native host connector or install plugins for missing APIs. Refer documentation for instructions."

Answer (score 2):

You are able to install: that is just a download. You are not able to run. To be able to run the downloaded `.AppImage` file,install the library fuse2:

```
sudo apt install libfuse2
```

Comment: If this answer allowed you to run the AppImage, then please accept this answer and feel free to ask a new question on the new problem that arrizes with this particular AppImage on your particular system.

Comment: Could you please explain in detail

Comment: Open the terminal, and copy/paste the given command in the terminal to install it in your system. Then press enter. You will need to provide your user password: type it when asked; you won't see nothing in the terminal while you give your password: that is normal and is a security measure. Then press Enter again to have apt install command to actually start.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my day :)

Comment: yes i have upvoted

Comment: @EkaveeraGouribhatla I see, you were not the one that asked the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since wayland I cannot use the app. There are problems in sharing the screenshot with the app probably.

Comment: @falematte any workaround?

Comment: nope. Shall we open a ticket somewhere?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: I switched to GNOME, I don't have nvdia-smi anymore but I am not sure this is due to this, otherwise ...................................

Answer (score 0):

For me it was easier downloading the Windows Desktop app and using wine to install it

```
sudo apt install wine
wine mathpix_snipping_tool_setup.v03.00.0091.exe
```

Comment: I get `ERROR:dxva_video_decode_accelerator_win.cc(1399)] DXVAVDA fatal error: could not LoadLibrary: msmpeg2vdec.dll: Module`